# If child process created by popen() is killed, parent process will quit, even with signal_handler() installed

Tags: c, posix, popen

The overall design of my program is:

1. I install a signal handler, which set a flag if some signals are sent;
2. I start an event loop
3. The event loop quits if flag is turned on, with some finalizing steps.

The code is roughly like this (and just in case someone would like to check the complete version, it can be found [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/main/c-cpp/cpp/06_poc/01_opencv-to-ffmpeg/3_with-signal-handler.cpp) and a `Makefile` is also prepared):

```
volatile sig_atomic_t ev_flag = 0;

static void signal_handler(int signum) {
    ev_flag = 1;
    char msg[] = "Signal caught\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
}

void install_signal_handler() {
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND;
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, 0)  + sigaction(SIGABRT, &act, 0) +
        sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, 0) + sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, 0) +
        sigaction(SIGPIPE, &act, 0) + sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, 0) +
        sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, 0) + sigaction(SIGTRAP, &act, 0) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction()");
        abort();
    }
}

int main(void) {
    install_signal_handler();
    FILE *child_proc;
    child_proc = popen(child_proc_cmd, "w");
    while (ev_flag == 0) {
        if (fwrite(data, 1, data_size, child_proc) != data_size) {
            perror("fwrite()");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe evloop quitted, gracefully\n");
    pclose(child_proc);
    return 0;
}
```

This design works well for most cases, except one: If the child process is somehow killed by `kill <pid>` or `kill -KILL <pid>`, my parent process won't reach

```
printf("\nThe evloop quitted, gracefully\n");
```

as expected, even if my `signal_handler()` is invoked. Any thoughts? Or any bugs in my current design?

Comment: it could be possible that kill command sends SIGKILL or SIGSTOP that cannot be caught or ignored. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGKILL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You never call `install_signal_handler()`, so your signal handler is never executed.
2. In signal handler you would write from null pointer: `write(STDOUT_FILENO, 0, strlen(msg));`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t ev_flag = 0;

static void signal_handler(int signum) {
    ev_flag = 1;
    char msg[] = "Signal caught :";
    char *sig = strsignal(signum);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));   // Write from buffer
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, sig, strlen(sig));   // Write signal string
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
}

void install_signal_handler()
{
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND;
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, 0)  + sigaction(SIGABRT, &act, 0) +
        sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, 0) + sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, 0) +
        sigaction(SIGPIPE, &act, 0) + sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, 0) +
        sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, 0) + sigaction(SIGTRAP, &act, 0) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction()");
        abort();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const char data[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n";
    size_t data_size = strlen(data);
    const char child_proc_cmd[] = "wc -l";

    install_signal_handler();    // Install signal handlers

    FILE *child_proc;
    child_proc = popen(child_proc_cmd, "w");
    while (ev_flag == 0) {
        if (fwrite(data, 1, data_size, child_proc) != data_size) {
            perror("fwrite()");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe evloop quitted, gracefully\n");
    pclose(child_proc);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Signal caught :Child exited
Signal caught :Broken pipe
fwrite(): Broken pipe

The evloop quitted, gracefully
```

Comment: Sorry I simplified my code too much. These two issues do not exist in my original code. The issue turns out to be that I cant set `SA_RESETHAND`. In your example, you may change `wc -l` to something that lasts longer, say, `sleep 10` and `kill` it. I believe you version still suffers from the issue as you have `SA_RESETHAND` as well.

Comment: `wc -l` works infinitely (until EOF) and i killed it from another terminal. My example exits gracefully with `act.sa_flags = 0`, as well as with `sleep 10` as a command. If your process get SIGPIPE because of some previous code, obviously `SA_RESETHAND` will reset signal handler for SIGPIPE to default and you don't catch it. Run your program under `strace` to see what's happening.

Comment: before I check what you said, I revised my question to include a link of a more complete test case. It is [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/main/c-cpp/common/04_posix-api/03_signal-handler/2_multithreading.c).

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Code from the link has nothing common with original except `sigaction()` call. I have no idea how relate it to the original question.

Comment: sorry the previous link is wrong, the correct one is [this](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/main/c-cpp/cpp/06_poc/01_opencv-to-ffmpeg/3_with-signal-handler.cpp)

Comment: @D.J.Elkind `act.sa_flags` is not initialized in your code. Set it to `0` if you need no any flags.

Comment: seems you are right, I checked `signal.h`, etc, seems nothing initializes it to `0` automatically..

Comment: yes I checked myself, ChatGPT gives wrong answer. I removed that comment and incorporate the revisions in the same file [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/main/c-cpp/cpp/06_poc/01_opencv-to-ffmpeg/3_with-signal-handler.cpp).

Comment: I briefly saw your new comment, yes that is also the worrying part--it means that some benign child processes can also make my parent process behave differently. My hope is that as long as the child process is not designed to cripple my parent process, my parent process can still run no matter what happens to the child process

Comment: @D.J.Elkind It should run unless child process intentionally send signals to it's parent. I removed ffmpeg-related stuff from your program - it does print `The evloop quitted, gracefully` after child process exited. Tested with `sleep 10` and `wc -l`. So the problem is somewhere else. Good hunting!

Comment: yes I am now playing with `strace` see if can find anything else lol